# If a laptop had a hard shutdown and was left unpowered in that state for 1 year, will the RAM still contain information?

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, data-recovery

If a laptop suffered from a shutdown (eg I pressed power key long enough till it shuts down) and has been left unconnected to the charger for 1 year and the hard disk of it was taken  out, will the RAM still contain information that can be used to say what the user was doing or which files he was looking at? Will it contain information like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The RAM requires power to hold it's data.  Not only that, the data in RAM has to be constantly refreshed.  Without power, RAM will lose its contents within a few seconds.  There are methods, like lowering the RAM's temperature that can extend it's ability to hold data.  However, that only adds seconds to the life of the data.

Answer (score 2):

After power loss, RAM retains its contents for seconds up to minutes. Not necessarily all of it, different memory chips would degrade at different rates. No two chips are the same, after all.

Experiments<sup>1</sup> have shown that freezing the RAM immediately allows almost complete data extraction even after multiple hours. However, it’s very unlikely there’d be much left after a year, even when cooled using liquid nitrogen.

1: “Memory forensic data recovery utilising RAM cooling methods” (DOI [10.4225/75/58a54cc3c64a2](https://ro.ecu.edu.au/adf/162/))

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No. Long answer: RAM is a form of *volatile memory*, which means that, when it loses power, it no longer can hold stuff. This is in contrast with *persistent storage*, which is what most HDDs and SSDs have nowadays. So, that means after the computer is turned off, data is not recoverable from RAM. If there wasn't enough RAM, swap space might contain some data, but swap space is on the persistent storage, which in your question has been taken out.